# Affine Hyperplane and linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I need help to proof:

An affine subspace $H$ in a normed space $E$, with $\text{codim}(E/H) = 1$, is an hyperplane if and only if there is a non-zero linear functional

$f: E→ \mathbb{R} $

such that

$H = \left\{ xϵE:f(x)=0 \right\} = Ker(f)$

Sorry for my english, I'm practicing.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use MathJax to properly format mathematics. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: What is $E$? Was that supposed to be $X$?

Comment: I just corrected the question, thank you.